# rails capybara - how to detect js clicking on a li (not a link or a button)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I have a js submit button that is a input element within an li.
So it is not a link or a button and presumably this is why the `click_on` isn't working right - I get

```
Failure/Error: click_on 'user_submit_action'  
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   no link or button 'user_submit_action' found
```

Code...

```
</fieldset>
      <fieldset class="actions"><ol>
       <li class="action input_action" id="user_submit_action"><input class="a1" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create User" /></li>
</ol></fieldset></form>  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this ?

```
find("#user_submit_action").find("input").click
```

You can see the doc : http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders.

Comment: How do I do this if there is no "id" for that element and only has "class"?

Comment: I think something like this `find(".user_submit_action").first().find("input").click` will work